# Clicking editable field brings up keyboard and ruins layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout which looks as I want until I click in an editable field, which then brings up the soft keyboard and ruins my layout by squashing everything and hides some fields. I have tried adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`,
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, putting the contents inside a `<ScrollView>`, adding `android:isScrollableContainer="false"` to many different containers, and other methods found in forums here, but nothing is working. Are there any other methods to keep layout fixed when keyboard is shown?

EDIT: Found a temporary fix. I found a question on here (don't have link atm) that suggested surrounding entire contents with scrollview and setting this attribute to scrollview     `android:fillViewport="true"`. The top linearlayout no longer squashes but the button in the bottom one still come up with the keyboard.

My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp">

<!-- Linear Layout that holds all Equipment information (List and Details) -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/linear_layout_border"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- Linear Layout for Equipment List -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/equipment_list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvequipments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/wash_count_list_item_states"/>


    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- End Linear Layout for Equipment List -->

    <!-- Linear Layout for Equipment List Details - Hidden Until a primary equipment is selected-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/equipment_list_details"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:visibility="invisible">
        <!-- Linear Layouts for Unavailable fields -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/unavailable_count"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/work_order_wash_count_unavailable"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/unavailable_count_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:focusable="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Linear Layout for Unavailable fields -->

        <!-- Hidden EditText for unavailable reason -->
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/unavailable_count_reason"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/work_order_wash_count_reason_unavailable"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <!-- Linear Layout for PLC replaced or reset -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/plc_replaced"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/work_order_wash_count_plc_replaced"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/plc_replaced_checkbox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:focusable="false" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Linear Layout for PLC replaced or reset -->

        <!-- Linear Layout for Single Pass -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/single_pass_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
                android:text="@string/work_order_wash_count_single_pass"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/single_pass_count"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLines="1" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Linear Layout for single pass -->

        <!-- Linear Layout for Double pass -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/double_pass_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:text="@string/work_order_wash_count_double_pass"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/double_pass_count"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLines="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Linear Layout for Double pass -->

        <!-- Linear Layout for Total pass -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/total_pass_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:text="@string/work_order_wash_count_total_pass"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/total_pass_count"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLines="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Linear Layout for Total pass -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/wash_count_save_button"
            style="@style/body_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/work_order_wash_count_save_button_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- End Linear Layout for Equipment List Details -->

</LinearLayout>
<!-- End Linear Layout for Equipment Section (List and Details) -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close_wash_counts"
            style="@style/body_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/close" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`